# How to pass custom variables to Flex applications

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex3, flashvars

I'm trying to write an application where parameters have to be passed to the application. In Flex builder I modified the  and  tags in the index.template.html, but when debugging I still don't see the variables passed (using from as3 the Application.application.parameters object)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after reading a post i found that I had made a stupid mistake.  I had added the 
"flashvars", "var1=blah&var2=blah..." to the **first** 
AC_FL_RunContent() which installs the Flash Player.  My bad.  As soon 
as I modified the index.template.html to add the "flashVars" to the 
2nd AC_FL_RunContent(), it worked like a charm.

Comment: There are actually 3 places in the default template you should add it to, just for compatiblity's sake.